# Moving std::optional<T>, and contained value, C++17

Tags: c++, move

```
// T is move-only
std::optional<T>&& foo() { 
   T t = MakeT();
   // ~T() invoked here
   return std::move(std::optional<T>(std::move(t)));
}


void bar() {
   auto opt = foo();
   // opt.has_value() is false here
}
```

Using a C++17-compatible compiler, I have a type `T` for which the above occurs. I do not understand the properties of `T` that cause this to occur, or how to force the **move**.

It seems like `t` is **moved** into the `std::optional` correctly - but **moveing** the local `std::optional` (a) resets the `std::optional`, and (b) fails to call `T`s **move-assignment** operator.

Comment: `foo` returns a reference to a local unnamed object that goes out of scope and dereferencing which leads to UB. So none of this stuff could work (regardless of `T`).

Comment: @user7860670 Perhaps I misunderstand the meaning of returning an r-value reference (what I assume is indicated by `&&` in the return signature). Is the local unnamed object not  **moved** into `opt` here, before going out of scope?

Comment: @Zach It is moved, but at the point where the move constructor is called, the object that the reference references (the temporary created by `std::optional<T>(std::move(t))`) is already destroyed, so you are trying to use an invalid reference causing undefined behavior, see linked duplicate. Temporaries are generally destroyed at the end of the full-expression they were created in, i.e. here after the return value has been initialized, but before the function returns.

Comment: It is indeed moved into `opt`. The problem is that it is an invalid reference referencing object that went out of scope at function `foo`.

Comment: You should just return `T` or `std::optional<T>` by-value and with `return t;`. That will automatically move construct `opt` from `t` in either case, because of special move rules for return statements and because of C++17 copy elision.

Comment: @walnut / @user7860670 - If I can summarize for my own understanding, the order-of-events is: (1) `t` **moved** into temporary (2) r-value reference created from temporary (3) function ends, temporary is destroyed, (4) r-value reference is returned, referencing destroyed temporary

Comment: @Zach Correct .

Comment: @walnut Great! Learnt something today. Thank you.